# Picketlink custom relationship duplicate record on DB

Tags: java, relationship, picketlink, java-annotations

I'have builded a custom relationship to allow Account to open a Module. So i copied  org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Grant and renamed it.
The relationship is created successfully, the database tables are created, but when the relationship is stored on the DB, the records are duplicated:
[image: Here an example]

For the same record there are 2 assignee and 2 module, so if i try to remove the module for instance, i get an exception.

I've read the [official guide](https://docs.jboss.org/picketlink/2/latest/reference/html/Creating_Custom_Relationships.html) but it use an annotation:

```
org.picketlink.idm.model.annotation.RelationshipIdentity
```

that not exists!

Anyone has experienced the same duplication error or tryed to build custom relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was in the entities for persisting the records on Database.
I have the classes *RelationshipTypeEntity* and *RelationshipIdentityTypeEntity* like suggested in the [official guide](https://docs.jboss.org/picketlink/2/latest/reference/html/chap-Identity_Management_-_Working_with_JPA.html#Mapping_Relationship_Types1).
Theese entity classes are sufficient! 
I added also ModuleUserRelationship that expands RelationshipTypeEntity, but in this way in the table i found a reference for the RelationshipTypeEntity table and another for the ModuleUser table.

So removing additional entity classes resolved my problem.